# iOS and Android Code GIT Clone conundrum

Tags: android, ios, git, git-clone

I have been working on a project for both native iOS and Android apps. Now that my parent projects are done, I need to run clones for them. These clones will use more or less the same code but with different languages, resources and possibly XIB files as well. I have been using GIT for code management and I google the best way to handle this and the suggested technique was with Forking which was no good because it started creating issues with different Package IDs in the projects.
Now, you know the problem that I am facing. I am looking for expert opinion to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how about Android, but for iOS you can use targets and then set which files should be used by selected target. Each target may have its own Info.plist file, different graphic assets and more.

Start with duplicating an existing target:

[image: duplicating Xcode target]

You will notice Info-copy.plist file, which is a setting file for the new target. 
Then use a proper scheme to run your new target:

[image: xcode schemes]

If it's not there, go to "Manage schemes" and press "Autocreate schemes now"

Comment: I have no idea, why I have forgotten about this feature. Oh the idiocy! I am going to try this one in iOS but the major issue still remains. The Android is bigger problem. I am going to wait for more answers and if I don't get any. I'll accept yours then. :)

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid we have a 1-1 copy of the app on Android, however I need to ask our dev what does it look like from a technical point of view

Comment: That would be awesome of you. Thank you!

Comment: Well, put simply: you have a source code, and another folder with assets like images, logos, and some configuration .xml. When bulding, you select the wanted assets and import to the project.

Comment: I should give it a go and will let you know about this.

Comment: have you used this feature for the files with the same name? Let's say that I have resources that I want to keep with the same name and mark the targets with the related files.

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid yes! but make sure they are located in the different folders, also notice the difference between groups of files Xcode & folders

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of dependencies between each other between the clones that are making it very difficult to use this approach. I am however, trying to create a static library and push all my main code in the library and the rest of the apps to be shell apps.